# Effect of Holding Power-On Button on MacPro

Tags: boot, mac-pro

I have a mid-2012 Mac Pro.  I've been using it for 11+ years (24 CPUs, 48GB RAM).  It's been a great workhorse.

Recently I had an SSD die.  It wouldn't boot because the drive itself was unrecognizable.

When I shut it down, I have to press and hold the ON button for a long time.  When I do this, it boots up to High Sierra just fine.  90%+ of the time, if I just power it on, then I get the circle with the line through it, and I have to turn it off and hold the power button.  Then it boots fine.

**Does anyone know how to get a Mac Pro to boot without having to hold down the ON button?**

And, I have another question about the ON button.  I unplugged my Mac while I swapped out the dead SSD, and then I held the power button down before I plugged the Mac back in.  When I did this, a very bright red light on the motherboard turned on (it lit up the dark room), and then several internal fans turned on high.  It blew a tremendous amount of dust out of the CPU box, which filled my room with dust.  (I had recently cleaned all dust off the motherboard, the ram, and inside the case, so such a dust plume was surprising -- it must have been hiding in the power supply.)  I held down the power button and it turned back off, then I held it down again and it booted normally.  **What is it that happened when I held down the ON button and plugged in the Mac?**

Comment: You've probably reset the SMC at some point during this but it might be worth doing again intentionally. Shut down. Mains plug out. Wait 15s. Plug back in, wait another 10s, press [tap don't hold] power button. Then go for the NVRAM, Cmd/Opt/P/R at the chimes. Hold until it restarts a 2nd time. I know these rarely do anything, but in this case I think it might just be worth it. If you ever get mobo lights, get a photo or check the numbers. There are many things they report. There are 2 sets of lights, on the mobo & on the daughtercard.

Comment: btw, holding the power button at power on is normally only done for firmware updates [one of which was introduced with High Sierra… which might be a clue]. idk what it does at any other time. If you can get to the desktop, check About this Mac, system report & get the Boot ROM & SMC versions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Boot ROM Version: MP51.0089.B00; SMC Version (system): 1.39f11; SMC Version (processor tray): 1.39f11

Comment: Ah, you're missing the firmware update. Boot ROM should be either 138 or 144, depending on whether you have a Metal-capable GPU. See https://support.apple.com/HT208898 and https://www.usedmacs.us/?1-to-the-latest-firmware-and-Boot-ROM-Version&art=how_to_mac_pro_firmware_upgrade Those download links may not work any more, in which case see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: I've never done this at any time other than with a regular system update, so I really don't know what to expect. You might be best to try this with a spare drive

Comment: Thanks again.  I just bought the SAPPHIRE Radeon PULSE RX 580 8GB GDDR5 card that is on the list you provided.  I think using a Metal compatible GPU will also solve some other vexing issues with my slow Windows VMs, and the way Fusion downgrades hardware acceleration to use Basic OpenGL, because it can't utilize the full OpenGL capabilities of my ATI Radeon HD 5770 driver.